# A property of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. I need to prove that there are two orthogonal unit vectors $u$
and $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$
 such that $u = (u_1, u_2, a)$ and $v = (v_1, v_2, b)$ if and only if $a^
2 + b^
2 ≤ 1$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you probably want to update your question with what you think would be a valid approach to the problem

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $|a|,\ |b|\leq 1$. Let $$ u=(\sqrt{1-a^2}\cos\ \theta ,
\sqrt{1-a^2}\sin\ \theta ,a ),\ v=(\sqrt{1-b^2}\cos\ \alpha ,
\sqrt{1-b^2 }\sin\ \alpha,b) $$

They are unit vectors. Hence $u\cdot v=0$ iff there is $\theta,\
\alpha$ s.t. $$\sin\ (\theta +\alpha ) =
\frac{-ab}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}}\ \ast$$

iff $\frac{|ab|}{\sqrt{(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}}\leq 1$ iff $a^2+b^2\leq 1
$.